# IntelliJ Node JS application configuration **error error=13, Permission denied**

Tags: node.js, jmeter

I am facing the problem with configuring **NodeJS application**.
**IntelliJ** is giving the following **error** when I am trying to execute the application.

> error=13, Permission denied

Comment: Well it appears to be a...permissions problem. Have you tried changing the file permissions? And also make sure that node.js is installed globally and not only for the superuser (if you are on *nix based OS). You can also check if the files are not locked by another process.

Comment: Got it running just issue this command on terminal                                                      chmod a+x  pathcode/node/src/api/index.js

Comment: And did that work?

Comment: yeh it was permission problem thnx